# Spark job dataframe write to Oracle using jdbc failing

Tags: scala, oracle11g, properties, apache-spark-sql, firewall

When writing spark dataframe to Oracle database (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit), the spark job is failing with the exception **java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**. The scala code is

```
dataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ipPort + ":" + sid, table, props)
```

Already tried setting below properties for jdbc connection but hasn't worked.

```
props.put("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
props.setProperty("testOnBorrow","true")
props.setProperty("testOnReturn","false")
props.setProperty("testWhileIdle","false")
props.setProperty("validationQuery","SELECT 1 FROM DUAL")
props.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true")
```

Based on the earlier search results, it seems that the connection is opened initially but is being killed by the firewall after some idle time. The connection URL is verified and is working as the select queries work fine.  Need help in getting this resolved.

Comment: Check if you are able to connect to the Oracle database using SQLDeveloper or SQLPlus.

Comment: Yes I am able to connect from Oracle SQLDeveloper but the connections over there as well get closed regularly. So, I need to reconnect many a times. Just a doubt, shouldn't it be manageable to check for closed connections using validation query and by setting other required jdbc parameters.